# The 'ismouseover' attribute stays in 'enteractions/exitactions' mode , how do I change the focus of the button ? please note the image (GIF)

Tags: c#, wpf

First and foremost, I apologize for my grammatical errors; my first language is `Persian` (Iran).

I created a button that has a series of effects and these effects work properly when the `WPF` window opens.
But when the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event is done and the `Openfiledialog` window opens, the button stays in focus mode (the `IsMouseOver` attribute stays in `EnterActions` mode). When I shift the focus of the button to another control, the `IsMouseOver` feature stays in `ExitActions` mode.

[image: OpenFileDialog]

I want the button to work exactly like when the window first opens and has no focus control.

```
private void UploadButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
            FirstName_TextBox.Focus();
            System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I might try clearing the focus explicitly (via ClearFocus()) right before you open the file dialog.

Comment: I did clear Focus but it didn't work (Keyboard.ClearFocus();).

Comment: Sorry, I meant ReleaseAllCapture() (this should remove the mouse capture), it's a member method you can call in the event handler.

Comment: Can you write the code?

Comment: Yea, sry my wpf is a little rusty!  The name is actually 'ReleaseMouseCapture.'  I primarly write cpp these days, but spent several years doing ui work in wpf.  I added an answer with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></Setter>
```

Details are in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/279481/the-ismouseover-attribute-stays-in-enteractionsexi.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the button isn't releasing the mouse capture.
Two possible fixes come to mind.

1. Hook up to the MouseLeftButtonUp event instead of the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event (the Button may not naturally release capture until after the preview event, but before the non-preview one).
2. Call ReleaseMouseCapture explicitly in the callback before you open the file dialog (see code below).

This assumes that the event handler is hooked up to the button, or one of its visual ancestors (like the owning UserControl or Window).

```
 private void UploadButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    ReleaseMouseCapture();
    FirstName_TextBox.Focus();
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new 
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;
}
```

Generally speaking you don't want variable names to look like type names, so I renamed the variable starting with a lower case letter (camelCase).

Other than that I copied the code in the original post and just added the "ReleaseMouseCapture" line.

PS: I believe you have to call OpenFileDialog.Show() to actually display the window (this wasn't the focus of the question, just thought I'd mention it).